# Record Mouse clicks and display on the button itself using WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a button. Each and every time the user clicks that button Message should be displayed on the button "1" 2nd time when the user clicks the button, it should display "2" and so on.
How do i do it?

```
enter code here
```

I have to do it using WPF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is just what you needed!

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace WpfApplication1
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
      /// </summary>
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
          public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              button1.Content = null;
          }

          private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {

              if (button1.Content==null)
              {
                  button1.Content = 1;
              }
              else
              {
                  button1.Content = (Int32.Parse(button1.Content.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
              }


          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I get an error telling that "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: have you set button1.content=null ??

Comment: If your button has some initial text on it, then you should compare the button context to it initial text at first, i.e. you should write a condition like this: if(button1.Content.ToString()=="SomeText") ...    in place of comparing with null

Comment: I got it!! I had to change the button content to "{Binding}"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM then create an property in Viewmodel and set default value 1 and also use Icommand for handle click event of Button. 
In ViewModel when you click on button then increase or change the value of your property.

In XAML bind Content property of button to ViewModel's property.